# Reshape multidimensional N-D array in matlab correctly without distorting data

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, permutation, reshape

So I have found *many* questions and answers about this on `SO` already and I think my approach should work as it is not very complicated. However I have tried every position for my time dimension possible and for me right now reshaping and keeping one dimension the same does not work:

I have a 400x400x20x24 array in which 400x400 is an image and 24 is a number of images at 20 times. I have to do an operation on each voxel and to make this quicker I want to reshape my array into a 2D matrix where one dimension is 20 and only has the time values. I know (or thought I knew)  how to do this and have tried every possible order of dimensions prior to reshaping, but none result in my old data:

```
array1 = rand(400,400,20,24);
```

This is how one voxel ove time looks

```
plot([1:20], squeeze(array1(200,200,:,12)))
```

[image: original]

```
twoD1 = reshape(array1, [], 20);
size(twoD)
    ans = 3840000 20
```

so far so good until I plot a pixel and its time values

```
plot([1:20], squeeze(twoD1(962400,:)))
```

[image: reshape1]

Hmmm wait a minute the dimension of size 20 is no longer the original dimension of size 20, maybe rearranging my original dimensions will affect this.

```
array2 = permute(array1, [3 1 2 4]);
array3 = permute(array1, [1 3 2 4]);
array4 = permute(array1, [1 2 4 3]);

twoD2 = reshape(array2, [], 20);
twoD3 = reshape(array3, [], 20);
twoD4 = reshape(array4, [], 20);

plot([1:20], squeeze(twoD2(962400,:)))
plot([1:20], squeeze(twoD3(962400,:)))
plot([1:20], squeeze(twoD4(962400,:)))
```

[image: reshape2]

[image: reshape3]

[image: reshape4]

I dont understand why it doesnt work. Ive looked at these questions, but they seem to suggest I do it right, right?

[Reshaping a matrix in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102216/reshaping-a-matrix-in-matlab)

[How do I resize a matrix in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793574/how-do-i-resize-a-matrix-in-matlab)

[Reshaping a 3 dimensional array to 2 dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004989/reshaping-a-3-dimensional-array-to-2-dimensions)

[Change a multidimensional vector to two dimensional vector matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838704/change-a-multidimensional-vector-to-two-dimensional-vector-matlab)

[MATLAB reshape matrix converting indices to row index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196250/matlab-reshape-matrix-converting-indices-to-row-index?rq=1)

[How to reshape matlab matrices for this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046415/how-to-reshape-matlab-matrices-for-this-example?rq=1)

[Reshape matrix from 3d to 2d keeping rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655878/reshape-matrix-from-3d-to-2d-keeping-rows?rq=1)

[Reshape 3d matrix to 2d matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256925/reshape-3d-matrix-to-2d-matrix)

Of course I also read:

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/permute.html

All to no avail. Someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Did you expect to see exactly the same plot as the first one? But in the first plot, you look at the central pixel of image 12, how do you make sure that you are looking at the same pixel of the same image in any of the last 4 plots?

Comment: This is just a matter of book keeping.  I've updated and fixed my answer -- I think it does what you want.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Well visually all pixels look the same, they are all exponential decays. Thats why I can vsually check if my t dimension is still the samen. To make sure I get the right pixel sub2ind can be used as chappjc showed.

Comment: That information was missing, since you used `rand` in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue to note is that `twoD1 = reshape(array1, [], 20);` does not do what you want since `array1` is `400x400x20x24`.  The `reshape` only works as intended if the last dimension is `20`:

```
twoD = reshape(permute(array1,[1 2 4 3]),[],20);
```

That gives you all pixels, all 24 images by 20 time points.  If you want to plot the 20 time points for pixel (200,200) for image 12, do the following:

```
[numRows,numCols,numTimes,numSlices] = size(array1);
imgInd = 12; pixRow = 200; pixCol = 200;
ind = sub2ind([numRows numCols numSlices],pixRow,pixCol,imgInd)
% ind = pixRow + numRows*(pixCol-1) + numRows*numCols*(imgInd-1)
plot(1:size(twoD,2), twoD(ind,:))
```

EDIT:  Sorry, I computed `ind` wrong first.  Works now.

Comment: Thanks! This is not the first time youve answered a question of mine. TwoD4 had the time dimension last, still I got it wrong. Ill check later this morning if thats where I went wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help again.  I think your mistake was the number `962400`.  The right number is the value of `ind` in my answer.